# NHibernate: Return a referenced property without lazy loading using SetProjection

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following two classes mapped:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
public class Bar
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following Criteria:

```
return Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>("f")
    .CreateAlias("f.Bar", "b")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("f.Bar"))
    .List<Bar>();
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
select b.Id from Foo f
inner join Bar on f.BarId = b.Id
```

Notice how only the Id of Bar is returned, rather than the entire class. How do I get all the columns of Bar instead?

Comment: In your code example you state .List<Bar>(); , however you say that only the Id of Bar is returned. Does that mean that you get a list of Bar's that only the Id property is hydrated?

Comment: You may want to consider switching to HQL unless you have specific requirements that force you to use criteria (dynamic searching is typically the big one).

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on your needs.

First of all **if you need to return entity Bar, then your initial Criteria must be of type Bar** so you just:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Bar>().
       .List<Bar();
```

If you need to add some restrictions based on Foo then there are two ways.

1. Use HQL

   `session.CreateQuery(`

   ```
       "select b " +
       "from Foo f " +
       "inner join f.Bar b " +
       "where f.Id = 9 ")
   .List();
   ```
2. Use query only property. Do this by adding access="noop" in your Bar mapping file.

   `<many-to-one name="foo" access="noop"  class="Foo"   column="FooFk"/>`

Note that your domain model doesn't have to change! You don't need to add that "foo" property/field in the Bar class.
Now you can use that property in your queries like:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Bar>()
    .CreateAlias("foo", "f")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("f.Id", 9))
    .List<Bar>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't fit into a single criteria, use `DetachedCriteria`:

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<Foo>("f")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("f.Bar"))
    // more filter criteria ...

return session.CreateCriteria<Bar>
    .SetProjection(Subqueries.PropertyIn("id", subquery));
```

which creates sql like this:

```
select Bar.*
from Bar
where Bar.id in (Select b.id from Foo f inner join Bar b on ...)
```

Is obviously only make sense if you have some filter criteria base on Foo in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If the above detached criteria query doesnt work out here is a simple HQL query that should do the trick.

```
var hqlQuery="select b from Foo as f inner join f.Bar as b";
```

Now run this query as follows:

```
Session.CreateQuery(hqlQuery).List<Boo>();
```

you can now add where condition to your query too if you want.

Hope this helps.. I can tell you how to do it with Criteria but I think this is a little easier for you to ustand as u seem to be comfortable with SQL.